# Bearing angle of the vehicle

Tags: obd-ii

I have logged some data from OBD-II port of a vehicle using Torque app. One of the parameters logged via GPS is "Bearing" which I suppose is the angle between North and vehicle direction of motion (?). If that is true, should the difference between each two consecutive data points give me the turning angle of the vehicle?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Uhm, so basically you think it's some sort of compass? Just a question to understand you before I answer. Which PID is it? (Hexadeciaml number).

Comment: Apparently it's not a PID, sorry for the wrong info! Because, it's related to the vehicle position and its data are logged via smartphone GPS that I used.